# AWT bridge's "Hello World"

Tags: swing, awt, javafx, embed

I've heard about the JavaFX->AWT bridge (or hack) for a moment now.

But examples I find are quite fuzzy or blur to me.

So, if anyone knows an "Hello World" example for this bridge I'd be really interested !

(Just to be clear I don't need a way to embed a Swing component in a JFX animation or to launch a JFX from a Swing based program, I really need to embed some JFX inside a panel).

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: You heard it from me. And of course it is fuzzy and not guaranteed to fork for a lifetime. Maybe you should try different approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to embed JavaFX inside Swing, I recommend to take a look at this [hack](http://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in).

Comment: This hack is not stable at the moment and does not seem to work in every situations.
I'll use JFX when there will be an official supported api for JFX integration inside Swing.

But thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

The link above does not work for JavaFX 1.2, see my [blog entry on this](http://blogs.oracle.com/clarkeman/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in).
Nonetheless, this is still a hack.

The [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) project is incorporating support for this.